# EDA - Everything is event architecture

Tags: events, architecture

I'm reading books about different architectures but this questions keeps bugging me.

**Is it possible to build frontend + backend application with some message broker in between that uses only events to communicate?**

If use EDA across whole application (frontend or multiple frontends) and the backend we would have truly async app.
Frontend can consume the events as well as sends them, same for backend, everything is loosely coupled. **Why there are no such solutions and most of the time we see REST or GQL, why not to use events all the way?**

Answer (score 0):

Because most web applications need synchronous operations in order to invoke logic on the server layer.  Although you *could* build such an architecture, you would end up rebuilding much of HTTP as a layer on-top of your event middleware.  That's why REST is so popular, it leverages all the semantic elements of HTTP that are necessary to build an application.

Yes you *could* define your 401 Unauthorized "event" when a client sends a particular event, but why do so when HTTP already does it, the browser already knows how to handle it, and all the frameworks will deal with it gracefully without throwing in a ton of extra plumbing.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting a frontend app to a message broker isn't usually safe. But, there's a way around using GraphQL.

AWS Amplify can help here. It lets you listen for changes in data with GraphQL subscriptions. Check how to set it up it [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/graphqlapi/subscribe-data/).

For backend updates, you can use AWS's AppSync and EventBridge. Set rules in EventBridge to catch events. These get logged in a DynamoDB events table proxied by GraphQL mutation operation happening in the cloud. The frontend can then keep an eye on these updates or listen for broadcasts. A DynamoDB table in this case would work as a broker and GraphQL as a communication channel.

If the frontend needs to send updates back, it can use a REST API. This way, when events are sent to the server, it replies with a 204 status. That means "received and okay."

In short:

- You can doesn't mean you should.
- You can use RxJS, REST, AWS Amplify with GraphQL (AppSync), and EventBridge for this setup.

I hope this helps!